# Считать один байт из файла

Tags: c++, файлы, потоки-данных, filestream

Как считать один байт из файла? Следующий код работает, но некоторые байты пропускаются (`0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d`) и считывается следующий за ними байт.

```
ifstream file(fileName, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
uint8_t s;
file >> s;
```

Пытался еще сделать вот так,

```
file.readsome(&s, 1);
```

но `uint8_t*` не кастится к `char*`.
Использую именно uint8_t потому, что насколько я знаю стандартом размер char-а не регламентирован.

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 5):

Я бы использовал `char` (чтоб он был не байтом - это надо потрудиться такое найти...) Тогда

```
file.get(char&);

или

file.read(char*,1);
```

Ну, а если строго `uint8_t` (который, готов спорить, у вас он просто `unsigned char`... если нет - то даже интересно, с чем вы таким имеете дело) - то

```
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&s),1);
```

Comment: Насколько вообще безопасно использовать reinterpret_cast? Просто хочется написать переносимую программу.

Comment: Как по мне, в данном случае - запросто.

Comment: А почему через перегруженный оператор некоторые байты не считываются не знаете? Файл в бинарном режиме открыт ведь.

Comment: `\r` `\n` видимо

Answer (score 1):

[ASCII](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

- `0x09` - горизонтальная табуляция (`\t`)
- `0x0a` - перевод строки (`\n`)
- `0x0b` - вертикальная табуляция
- `0x0c` - «прогон страницы», новая страница - команда для принтера начать печать с новой страницы
- `0x0d` - возврат каретки (`\r`)

Выглядит так, как-будто вы читаете всё таки текстовый файл как текст, может быть оставить в конструкторе только `std::ifstream::binary`?

В крайнем случае всегда есть сишный `fread()`.

Answer (score 0):

Для чтения файлов байтами есть специально для этого предназначенная функция fread(). Используйте ее.

Comment: Это все-таки наследие С,  я думал в stream-ах есть замена для нее.

Answer (score 0):

В C++ очень много *умных* функций форматированного ввода, таких-как **>>**. Не пачкайтесь, а пользуйся **std::basic_istream::read**.

Comment: Ваш `read` наглухо зависнет в ожидании, если попытается прочитать больше, чем есть в файле. Нужен именно `readsome()`.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно стандарту ISO/IEC 14882, `<cstdio>` такая же часть С++, как и `<iostream>`. Поэтому никто не мешает его использовать там, где это удобно. Ведь никто не переживает насчет такого "наследия с", как операции `+=`, `%=` 
Никто и не помышляет убрать из С++ "наследие С", наоборот, на повестке дня добавление в стандарт С++ разного рода удобных инициализаций, которые появились в C11. Кстати, у `<iostream>` нет никаких преимуществ перед `<cstdio>`.

Comment: И вот это поправте - "там, где это ."